# JComboBox displays duplicate copies of the same object stored in an List JAVA

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I've got a `List` that stores custom `objects` of category type.  This `List` is in `Control` class.  There is no problem in populating the `List`, it works as expected.  The problem arises when I invoke the `populateComboBox()` method which is in the `View` class.

**The Problem:** the first time the `populateComboBox()` method is invoked, the `JComboBox` displays all the objects in the `List`.  The second time `populateComboBox()`method is invoked, the `JComboBox` displays duplicate copies of the objects.

**Example** if I populate the said `List` with two `objects` of Category type (lets name them `C1` & `C2`) and invoke the `populateComboBox()` method, the `JComboBox` displays `C1` `C2`.  When invoked the second time it displays `C1` `C2` `C1` `C2`.  The third time, `C1` `C2` `C1` ``` C2``C1 ``` `C2` and so on...

Here is the class content of the Category class:

```
public class Category 
{
    private String catName; 

    public Category()
    {

    }

    public Category(String str)    {
        this.catName = str;
    }


    public String getCatName() 
    {
        return catName;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return catName;
    }
}
```

Here is a section of my Control class:

```
public final class Control 
{
    private static List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<Category> getCatList()
    {
        return categoryList;
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the `populateComboBox()` method in the view class:

```
{
    List<Category> catList = Control.getCatList();
    for(Category cat: catList)
        {
            selectCatComboBox.addItem(cat);
        }
        addItemDialog.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried to keep things at the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
selectCatComboBox.removeAllItems();
```

before you start adding new items.

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy response. It worked!!